# A problem upon function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Function series $\sum_{n=1 }^{ \infty} u_{n}(x)$ converges to $S(x)$ in bounded interval $[a,b]$, if every $u_n(x)$ is non-negative and continuous in $[a,b]$.

prove that $S(x)$ attains its infimum in $[a,b]$

This is one of the problem in my homework, but I'm not quite convinced with the answer, which uses the hypothesis that $S(x)$ is well-defined everywhere. If need, I can post that proof.

(PS I've asked my TA, but he couldn't give a convincing explanation. And can't find another answer through Google.)

Comment: Is the convergence uniform?

Comment: @BolzWeir no, it just said  $\sum u_n(x)$ converges to $S(x)$ .

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very hard, normally only if $\sum { { u }_{ n }\left( x \right)  } $ be uniformly converges in $[a,b]$, can make $S(x)$ continuous, then it can attains its infimum (of course supremum also) in $[a,b]$ definitely. Just convergence can not make $S(x)$ continuous.

But please note there is one more condition: ${ u }_{ n }\left( x \right) \ge 0$. By just adding this condition, $S(x)$ does attain its infimum in $[a,b]$. (only infimum! not supremum) This is how we can make this proof:

Because $S(x)=\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ { u }_{ n }(x) }, \quad x\in [a,b],\quad { u }_{ n }\left( x \right) \ge 0$,

$\Rightarrow S(x)\ge 0$

Then $S(x)$ has Lower Bound. Then it has Greatest Lower Bound (or infimum), and we let it be $m$.

$$m=\underset { x\in [a,b] }{ inf } S(x)$$

So $\exists$ series $ \left\{ { x }_{ n } \right\} \subset [a,b],\quad s.t.\quad \lim _{ n\rightarrow +\infty  }{ S\left( { x }_{ n } \right)  } =m$.

Because $ \left\{ { x }_{ n } \right\}$ has boundary，so there must exists a convergent subsequence ${ x }_{ { k }_{ n } }\rightarrow { x }_{ 0 }\in [a,b]$ (Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem).

And our very task is to prove that:

$$S({ x }_{ 0 })=m$$

Which means $S(x)$ attains the infimum $m$. We can use "proof by contradiction" to prove this: If that's not the case, only $S({ x }_{ 0 })>m$ is possible, because $m$ is infimum. Then we can find a number $\alpha$ so that

$$S({ x }_{ 0 })>\alpha>m$$

For the point ${ x }_{ 0 }$,
$$S\left( { x }_{ 0 } \right) { =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { S }_{ n }\left( { x }_{ 0 } \right)  }  }$$

Because its limit $S(x_0)>\alpha$,  for $n$ sufficiently large, we can find a $n_0$ so that $S_{n_0}(x_0)>\alpha$.

Note the $S_n({ x }_{ 0 })$ is partial sums -- a finite sum of continuous functions, hence $S_n(x_0)$ is continuous. So $\exists$ a small interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, for all $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, we have $S_{n_0}(x)>\alpha$.

$$\because { x }_{ { k }_{ n } }\rightarrow { x }_{ 0 }\in [a,b]$$

When $n$ is sufficiently large, all $\{x_{k_n}\}$ will go inside $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, then we have,

$$S_{n_0}(x_{k_n})>\alpha$$

Again, $S_n({ x }_{ 0 })$ is partial sums, which limit is $S(x_0)$, we get:

$$S(x_{k_n})\ge S_{n_0}(x_{k_n})>\alpha$$

Now we let the $n$ goes to infinity, we already know that $\lim _{ n\rightarrow +\infty  }{ S\left( { x }_{ n } \right)  } =m$, and $x_{k_n}$ is a subsequence of $x_n$, then $S(x_{k_n}) \rightarrow m$. Therefore we get the limit

$$m \ge \alpha$$

Contradiction!